# MathJax html render to pdf

Tags: php, pdf, converters, dompdf, mathjax

I am trying to make an online quiz application where the user will be presented with a quiz that contains text, images and math equations. I also want the user to be able to print that quiz. I am using MathJax to display the equations.

If the quiz contains just text and images but no math equations, I can use DomPdf to convert the quiz HTML to a PDF and have the user print it.

However, how can I go about creating a PDF that has both the content from the HTML tags in the quiz and the math equations from the quiz rendered by MathJax?

Answer (score 1):

According to this post: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mathjax/forums/forum/948700/topic/3819537
wkhtmltopdf can convert the mathjax if you force a delay on the javascript rendering. I just got finished talking to a guy here:
[Printing the current page to pdf using wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983018/printing-the-current-page-to-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf/15983040#15983040)
about how to get a page saved to pdf using wkhtmltopdf from php. If you put those two things together, I think you can get what you want.